# Access non standard file descriptors of child process

Tags: rust

I have a child process which has inputs/outputs (pipes) on non standard file descriptors (not on fd0/stdin, fd1/stdout, fd2/stderr).

How can I access them? I don't see anywhere in the documentation that allows this or maybe I am missing something: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Stdio.html

It needs to work for Windows and Mac.

Comment: Why do you believe that this **can** be cross-platform?

Comment: @Shepmaster Is it possible to get it working for windows and mac?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such concept in Windows

Comment: well there is some handle inheritance but I believe it is very different in API

Comment: Is there a solution for mac?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Unix-specific API in the standard library to do this, specifically with the [`FromRawFd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/io/trait.FromRawFd.html) trait:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;
use std::os::unix::io::{FromRawFd, RawFd};

let fd: RawFd = 3; // example non-standard file descriptor
let mut file = unsafe { File::from_raw_fd(fd) };

// ...
```

Note that `from_raw_fd` says this:

> This function is also unsafe as the primitives currently returned have the contract that they are the sole owner of the file descriptor they are wrapping. Usage of this function could accidentally allow violating this contract which can cause memory unsafety in code that relies on it being true.

So you need to make sure that the `File` returned has unique ownership of the file descriptor (which is why the function is marked as unsafe).

Comment: Thanks for the possible solution but I need it cross platform, and will this work when spawning a process?

Comment: This is how you would write to fd 3 _as the child process_, but it doesn't say how to read the output of a such a child process that you might spawn.